# iPhone APNS Works From Command Line Only

Tags: php, iphone, apple-push-notifications

I've been developing an iPhone app using the Push Notification Services. Yesterday my PHP script was running fine when I accessed the url (ex. www.website.com/script.php), but now it no longer works.

The weird thing is that when I run the PHP script from the terminal (ex. "php script.php") everything works fine and the Notification is sent to the app.

I've recreated my SSL certificate and .pem a number of times so I feel like that's not the issue, since it already works on the server, just from the command line. I have also tried running exec("php script.php") inside the PHP script with no luck.

I'll post my code below. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    $passphrase = 'password';
    $message = 'This is a message';

    $ctx = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

    // Open a connection to the APNS server
    $fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT |STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);
```

The output is: "Failed to connect: 0".